# How can I use generics to specify the type of an out parameter in a base class' method?

Tags: c#, generics, exception, enterprise-library

I am wrapping the ExceptionManager in Microsoft's Enterprise Library's Exception Handling block, and I want to allow for consumers of my wrapper to specify which exception types are allowed to be rethrown by instantiators of the wrapper. Like so:

```
public class MyExceptionManager<T> : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionManager where T: MyCustomException
{
    ...
    public void LogWrapAndRethrow(Exception e, T t)
    {
        base.HandleException( e, "MyPolicyName", out t);
    }
...
}
```

I'd like for users to be able to make:

```
var em = new MyExceptionManager<MyCustomExceptionClass>();
var x = new MyCustomExceptionClass();
em.LogWrapAndRethrow(new Exception(),x);
```

...and have it checked at compile time

Here is the signature of the base method:

```
public bool HandleException(Exception exceptionToHandle, string policyName, out Exception exceptionToThrow);
```

It's not a generic class.

Unfortunately, I keep getting "the best overloaded match for... has some invalid arguments", even though T is constrained to a type that inherits from Exception. If I manually create and assign an Exception variable, it works as an output parameter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `base.HandleException` generic as well ?

Comment: @Selman22 no, added content to explain

Comment: You're trying to do something that's not allowed.  The base class can't return a T in the out parameter because the parameter is declared as Exception (I assume).  Your T might be MyCustomExceptionClass, but you cannot guarantee that the method won't try to assign an ArgumentNullException to the parameter (from the compiler's point of view, not the method contract).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument you use for an `out` parameter has to *exactly* match the declared parameter type. As `HandleException` has a third parameter `out Exception exceptionToThrow`, that won't work at the moment.

Given that you don't need the exception to come back out of your method, it's simplest to write the method as:

```
public void LogWrapAndRethrow(Exception e, T t)
{
    Exception tmp = t;
    base.HandleException( e, "MyPolicyName", out tmp);
}
```

Now you're calling the method with an argument of type `Exception`, so that's okay.

Comment: what happens if I `throw t;`? will it be mutated by the call to the base method?

Comment: @ChrisMcCall that depends on the contract of the base method.  Is it documented?

Comment: @ChrisMcCall See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee763096.aspx.  You should rethrow only if HandleException returns true, and you should throw `t ?? e`, effectively.  Also note that by putting this logic in its own method, you're losing (potentially valuable) stack trace information.

Comment: thanks @phoog I will test for any loss of stacktrace and take appropriate measures.